# C# Out Parameter

Tags: c#, .net

Why it is necessary for the out parameter to be assigned to before it leaves the current method?
Can someone please elaborate me what is going inside the shell? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out signifies a reference parameter. Sometimes methods must return more than one value and not store class state. Out fills these requirements. With it we pass parameters whose changes are realized in their calling methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why it is necessary for the out parameter to be assigned to before it leaves the current method?

Think of an `out` parameter as an extra return value. Just as you can't return from a non-void method without specifying the return value, you can't return from a method with an `out` parameter without setting a value for the parameter.

This in turn allows the argument for an `out` parameter to be definitely assigned after the method has completed, because it will definitely have been given a value by the method:

```
int value;
Foo(out value);
Console.WriteLine(value); // This is fine
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is designed in this way.That is the difference between `out` and `ref` parameters.By declaring an argument as `out`, the method guarantees that it will set the value of the argument.By `ref`, it doesn't have to.If you don't want an `out` use `ref`.

Comment: Of course, with `out` the method also guarantees that it will never _read_ the value of the parameter before it has _written_ to it at least once. On the other hand, with `ref` the caller will have to make sure the variable is definitely assigned. So I guess we could say that `ref` imposes some restrictions to the caller, while `out` restricts the implementation.